# UITableView lag when scrolling, each cell contains 4 UIButtons and 4 UILables

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

in my app I have a `UITableView`. Each row in the table contains 4 UIImages and 4 UILabels, images size is around 50k per image. The table seems to lag a little after about 10 rows. I know the images take up some space but if I am using the cell reuse identifier shouldn't it be smooth? Code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {



        if((int)indexPath.row*4+i<[self.currentUser.friends count]) {


            UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];
            [button setTag:(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
            button.clipsToBounds = YES;
            UILabel *label = cell.labels[i];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(friendTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressFriend:)];
            [button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

            //to unhide the hidden buttons and labels if it's a reused cell
            [button setEnabled:YES];
            [button setHidden:NO];
            [label setHidden:NO];

            //set username and profile pic
            PFUser *user =self.currentUser.friends[(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
            label.text=user.username;
            PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"profilePic"];
            [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }
            }];

        }


}
```

The inner loop sets the background images for the buttons which are images downloaded from Parse.com. I was originally using a `UIScrollView` and placing buttons on that, but have now switched to putting them in a table so I can take advantage of cell reuse for memory benefits. Works better than before but it's still lags. Any tips on what I can do to improve it?

EDIT: I have now added an image cache to store image locally, images are now only downloaded once. The are stored in a `NSMutableDictionary` named images. code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"offset %f",self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
    for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {



        if((int)indexPath.row*4+i<[self.currentUser.friends count]) {



            UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];
            [button setTag:(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
            button.clipsToBounds = YES;
            UILabel *label = cell.labels[i];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(friendTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressFriend:)];
            [button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

            //to unhide the hidden buttons and labels if it's a reused cell
            [button setEnabled:YES];
            [button setHidden:NO];
            [label setHidden:NO];

            //set username and profile pic
            PFUser *user =self.currentUser.friends[(int)indexPath.row*4+i];
            label.text=user.username;

            UIImage *cachedImage = self.images[@(indexPath.row*4+i)];
            if (cachedImage) {
                NSLog(@"Have image");
                [button setBackgroundImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

            else {
                NSLog(@"Download image");
                //download code
                PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"profilePic"];
                [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        self.images[@(indexPath.row*4+i)] = image;
                        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                    }
                }];

            }
```

Seems a little better now though still a little lag. Is it okay to store images like this in a dictionary? Won't it take up 50kb*number of images in the memory now? The alternative would be writing it to a file and then pulling images as needed but that would require converting the file data to images which would take up resources like when I was constantly converting from data downloaded on Parse.com before.

Edit:

For anyone interested, I solved the problem it was:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

that was causing the lag. seems like using layers is system intensive. removed that code and the difference is like night and day. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag and the memory usage are different concerns. You can only be sure by profiling the app but, I think your main problem is that you're creating 4 `UIImage` instances using `imageWithData:` within your delegate method. This means that the device is spending a lot of time to decompress the downloaded image data every time it needs to display a new row. One thing to note here is that, the decompression doesn't take place when you call the `imageWithData:` method. It takes place when you display the image on the screen (UIKit does lazy loading).

There are a few ways you can approach the problem. Your best bet would be using smaller images there if possible. If not, then you can download images that have a high chance of being visible beforehand in a separate thread.

**Edit :**
Storing all the images in a cache would of course cause memory issues. You can cache them using the `NSCache` class, which will automatically clear the cache when memory is low. The usual approach in this case is using a 2 level cache, the first one being the `NSCache`, and the second one being a disk based cache. In order to not slow things down, the disk based caching should be done in a separate thread of course, otherwise it would basically be the same thing you were doing before. There's even a library called `SDWebImage` that does this but you're using Parse so you can't use that directly.

There's a possible trick you can do to make iOS decode the image data before it gets displayed on the screen. It involves decompressing the data, drawing it on a new context and then creating a new `UIImage` from that in a separate thread. `SDWebImage` uses a similar method.

Comment: What about if all the images are already downloaded though? i.e. if I turn off wifi and the app is loaded I can still scroll the table, it's not downloading images.

Comment: I haven't used Parse, but my guess is that its SDK is caching the images you have downloaded. In any case, the decompression will take place regardless of caching  and that's the main cause of the lag. Use the profiler to be sure. Profile is your friend :)

Comment: Which instrument should I be using in profile? What should I be looking for? I'm not very experienced with it. thanks

Comment: You should select "Time Profiler" in Instruments. This tutorial shows the basics you need to be familiar with on an example case of laggy scrolling TableView, similar to yours. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: So I am now downloading the images just once and storing them in a cache, Performance seems slightly better though still not great. Wouldn't it be a problem keeping that dictionary in the memory now with 50kb*no. of images? Question edit above

Comment: thanks for that I'll take a look at it. I actually just did a memory profile on my app. 64 images is taking up 4.5mb in the app. That doesn't really seem like a lot in the grand scheme of things. I wondering if it's something else in my table code that's doing it. Maybe I'm repeatedly adding long press gestures that is slowing things down.

Comment: I don't thing gestures would be the main issue but they might add to the problem. Btw, as I said before, you need to make a time profile not a memory profile. This way you can find out what takes so much time during scrolling.

Comment: I did that 80% of the time is spent in the main thread. Took gestures out, it makes not difference so it's not that.

Comment: That's expected, because all the UITableView delegate methods are executed on the main thread. You should drill down a bit to see more detailed timings about the cell generation and display process

Comment: oh my god, I figured it out. button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2; button.clipsToBounds = YES;. I removed that, left the images as squares and it is much much better

Comment: I had completely skipped that portion of your code :) Yes, image masking or effects such as drop shadows take a lot of time.

Comment: has made a huge difference, even minimising the app on the iPhone now is smooth as it should be, not stuttering. I have added many more users now too and it's still silky smooth. I can move that code that creates circular images to a cgimage context when a user creates a profile, and use a square image instead of putting layers over it. I'll deff take a look at improving the cache too incase it gets too big. right now it's good though. thanks for all your help, lot of good pointers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things happening here.

1. You are adding another gesture recognizer every time the cell is reused.  And adding another target to your button every reuse as well. Those probably are not causing slow scrolling but they will cause problems with how those items work
2. Are you cancelling the network request once the cell is not visible anymore or has been reused?

Comment: Not cancelling the request anywhere no. Do I need to cancel it? At some point the images have to be downloaded.